# JMS\Serializer OBJECT_TO_POPULATE

Tags: php, symfony, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

Is it possible deserialize to an object with JMS\Serializer?

I don't see n option like the one Symfony Serializer has:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#deserializing-in-an-existing-object

```
$serializer->deserialize($data, Person::class, 'xml', [AbstractNormalizer::OBJECT_TO_POPULATE => $person]);
```

in JMS\Serializer

```
public function deserialize(string $data, string $type, string $format, ?DeserializationContext $context = null)
```

Comment: Seems like it is possible, as described here https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/object_constructor

Comment: Does anyone know how to actually implement the `Register ExistingObjectConstructor` part of the link above?